# play segment of audio from start time to end time and simulteneousely vertical line on graph should move from start to end point.MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, playback, speaker

i have matrix for umber of speaker involved in conversation and their start and end time..as below

```
segmentation_result=
            start time  end time  
 speaker1    1           1095 
 speaker2    10.95       20.67
 speaker3    20.67       35.54
```

i want to play segment of each speaker,new_seg is a column vector of original speech signal,if i have a time i can calculate size of segment by multiplying that time with Fs(16000),where first segment always start from 1.i tried a code like below

```
count=0;
for i=1:length(segmentation_result(:,1))
    count=count+1;
    if count==1
       player=audioplay(new_seg(segmentation_result(1):segmentation_result(i,2)*Fs));
       lay(player);
    else 
       player=audioplay(new_seg(segmentation_result(i,1):segmentation_result(i,2)*Fs));
       play(player);
    end
end
```

but that player is getting override...that's why only last executed one is playing...

i made  graph of new_seg speech signal,in which x-axis is time and y-xis is amplitude values of new_seg data.i have shown the vertical line on the graph where there is speaker change points.now i want that vertical line should move automatically from speaker segment's start time to end point and at the same time that segment should play also.

your help will be appreciated..